# Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private' - Firebase throws error

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, angularfire, angularfire2

I am working on application using angular and  firebase. I installed firebase with the instructions given on site and the versions as follows,

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "^4.8.1",
```

but the following error comes

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts(4,33):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'. 
>   node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/core/AuthTokenProvider.d.ts(17,39):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's a **[known issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/388)** that it's a problem with the newest npm firebase package (v4.8.1).

You need to roll back your firebase version back to 4.8.0. It was an issue with type definitions and its no longer work after updating from 4.8.0 to 4.8.1.

To fix this one,

**Step 1:**
Uninstall with the following command

```
npm uninstall --save firebase
```

**Step 2:**
Now, open your package.json file. There, you will find:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"
```

**Step 3:**
Below this line, add a this line (without the Caret(^) symbol): and save

```
"firebase": "4.8.0"
```

**Step 4:**
Now do an npm install. Your app should work

**Latest Update**

This specific issue has been resolved with the pull request **[`#391`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/391)**. Ionic team will also be rolling back part of the change that surfaced this so you shouldn't see the issue any more  in the next release.

Comment: Version -
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "4.8.0",
Also tries this combination
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4", OR "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.5",
    "firebase": "4.8.0",

Tried with Yarn as well as Npm

Has anybody still facing the problem.

Facing problem in this git repo
https://github.com/Sandeep3005/ng-chat-app.

Can anybody take a look

Comment: With AF2 and firebase making constant changes, this is going to be a fluid answer. @SandeepChikhale would you mind updating answer below since you are the top answer?

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE April/2018:

package.json:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
"firebase": "^4.12.1",
```

npm install

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

**1.** Inside package.json, remove `^` from `"firebase": "^4.8.1"`

**1.1** Downgrade Firebase from 4.8.1 to 4.8.0 by changing **4.8.1** to **4.8.0**

**1.2**  End result should look like this: `"firebase": "4.8.0"`

**2.** Run `npm update` in the Project Root. NPM will downgrade Firebase for ya

**3.** Run `ng serve --open` to check for compilation errors. There shouldn't be any.

**4.** Enjoy!

**Reason:**

Firebase had introduced some breaking changes that AngularFire2 had not coped up with yet. Until the AngularFire2 team work it out, this will be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

firebase version 4.8.2 works for me:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "4.8.2",
```