# Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'. Firebase web app

Tags: angular, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm developing an application with Firebase, when I try to run `ionic Cordova emulate android` I see the following error

> Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'

I used the firebase version `"firebase": "^4.8.0"` without using angularFire.
 I did a lot of research and the following problem was already found by users of `Firebase 4.8.1`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949311/cannot-find-module-firebase-app-types-private-firebase-throws-error).

It has solved the problem by installing `version 4.8.0` that would be the one I'm using. I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall `firebase` but it did not work. Can someone help me?
The complete error is as follows:

> [11:18:34]  typescript:
>   Project/paystation/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts,
>   line: 4
>               Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.
>
> L3:  import { FirebaseApp } from '@firebase/app-types';
>
> L4:  import { FirebaseService } from '@firebase/app-types/private';
>
> [11:18:34]  typescript:
>   ...station/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/core/AuthTokenProvider.d.ts,
>   line: 17
>               Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.
>
> L16:  getToken(forceRefresh: boolean): Promise;
>
> L17:  addTokenChangeListener(listener: (token: string | null) => void): void;
>
> L18:  removeTokenChangeListener(listener: (token: string | null) => void): void;
>
> Error: Failed to transpile program
>
> at new BuildError (C:\Users\domy9\cordova_project\ionic_project\paystation\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
>   at C:\Users\domy9\cordova_project\ionic_project\paystation\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:159:20
>   at Promise ()
>   at transpileWorker (C:\Users\domy9\cordova_project\ionic_project\paystation\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
>   at Object.transpile (C:\Users\domy9\cordova_project\ionic_project\paystation\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
>   at C:\Users\domy9\cordova_project\ionic_project\paystation\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
>   at

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private' - Firebase throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949311/cannot-find-module-firebase-app-types-private-firebase-throws-error)

Comment: got the same error

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem but i fix it with

```
npm install firebase@4.8.0
```