# Still receiving Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'. after rolling back to 4.8.0

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

This question / error keeps popping up on stack over flow

The general consensus is to roll back firebase to "firebase": "4.8.0",

In my case this has not fixed the problem.

```
[14:29:11]  typescript: C:/projects/Ionic/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts, line: 4
            Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.
```

Has any one else still facing this issue after rolling back?

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^4.1.1",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "4.8.0",
    "install": "^0.10.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
```

Comment: check the answer at the last https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949311/cannot-find-module-firebase-app-types-private-firebase-throws-error/47949323#47949323

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, I have followed these steps but get the exact same error when I try and build the project.