# Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private' still trap on it

Tags: firebase

Any one that can help me with this!

I tried everything that I had read here a couple of times, and tried to recreate the project, but still having that burning error. I noticed that each time I import AngularFireDatabase the error pops.

> ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts(4,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'. node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/core/AuthTokenProvider.d.ts(17,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.

appears! any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with the current firebase package:
[StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949311/cannot-find-module-firebase-app-types-private-firebase-throws-error/47949323#47949323)

Comment: I tried doing that, but still getting the same error. Please bear with me, kinda new in ionic firebase. Appreciate your help :D

Comment: Hmmm I am sorry then :/ Didnt find anything else. Ill tell you if I find something :D
Your welcome and have fun learning !

Comment: Weird thing is, after I run ionic serve, that error will pop out. And the if i save any random .ts file, my app works perfectly fine? Is that okay? I mean, im pretty sure it will affect things if I am going to deploy my first app right?