# Cannot find module '@firebase/auth-types'

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

I have been creating an app with ionic and firebase. I keep getting the following error.

> Cannot find module '@firebase/auth-types'

The error comes for firebase v 4.9.1. I tried downgrading to 4.8.0 as suggested in some of the answers in StackOverflow but no luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949311/cannot-find-module-firebase-app-types-private-firebase-throws-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private' - Firebase throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949311/cannot-find-module-firebase-app-types-private-firebase-throws-error)

Comment: @PeterHaddad as mentioned I tried the other suggestions which you have also pointed out but it did not work.